# Dreamweaver Disable checkout when file is already checked out on other PC?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Is this feature possible in Dreamweaver to disable the checkout for someone if the file is already checked out on someone else PC.

like its on TFS (Team Foundation Server) i-e if file is checked out with person-A for editing purpose then person-B can not edit the file or checkout the file for editing purpose.

So want to know if its possible on Dreamweaver, if so how to achieve this?

I tried looking for options in Dreamweaver but couldn't find it myself. May be i am looking in wrong Place.

Comment: Are you using TFS to store the source code? Or is this just in Dreamweaver?

Comment: @DaveShaw
  Right now i am just using dreamweaver, and may be i use SVN with dreamweaver, but need to learn SVN settings too later.
Right now just want to know how it is possible with dreamweaver only.